# display img fadeIn effect during loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load, fadein

l didn't managed to find a way to `display` my mosaic's img with a `fadeIn` effect during `loading`.

HTML :

```
<ul id="mosaic">
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art1.jpg" alt="Woman in yoga position with a smoke effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art2.jpg" alt="Woman in yoga position with a paint effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art3.jpg" alt="Woman face with a paint effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art10.jpg" alt="Woman dancing hip-hop with a paint effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art5.jpg" alt="Man with a paint effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art2.jpg" alt="Woman in yoga position with a paint effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art4.jpg" alt="Woman face with a paint effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art2.jpg" alt="Woman in yoga position with a paint effect"></li>
     <li  class="item"><img src="img/art7.jpg" alt="Woman with a paint effect"></li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
$(function() {
    $('#mosaic').find('img').each(function() { 
        var src = $(this).data('src');
        if (src) {
            var img = new Image();
            img.style.display = 'none';
            img.onload = function() {
                $(this).fadeIn(1000);
            };
            $(this).append(img);
            img.src = src;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I would say your approach isn't probably the best on what you are trying to achieve. Why would you append an img element inside an img element? Also please add the img.src = src on the top of img.onload function declaration.

Comment: Don't  really know, l've tried too many things... Do you have a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems working like this.

JS :

```
$(function() {
    var img = $('#mosaic').find('img');
    img.css('opacity', '0');
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        img.fadeTo(1500, 1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(this).hide().fadeIn(1000);`